# To find the sum of all int present in a string

Tags: c++, string, sum, integer

```
#include <string>
#include<ctype.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){

string s="124j3a.n2-'ad2'&1#vvg6";

string a="";

int digit,sum(0),temp;

for(char c:s){
     if(isdigit(c)){
       a+=c;    
    }   
}
digit=stoi(a); 

while (digit>0)
{
  temp=digit%10;
  sum+=temp;
  digit/=10;
}
cout<<sum;
    return 0;
}
```

so in this case the output sum will be 21 (1+2+4+3+2+2+1+6)

I've written this solution and code is working fine but
is there a better way to find the sum of all integers present in string s.

Comment: your code finds the sum of all digits. The sum of integers is different

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of the fact that a single char containing a digit can be easily converted to an integer value by subtracting `'0'` from it.

```
int sum{0};
for (char c : s) {
    if (isdigit(c)) {
        sum += c - '0';
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, I din't know that you could convert str to int by -'0', this was really helpful,

Answer (score 0):

Instead of appending each digit you find to a string and calculating it afterwards, you could immediately sum the found digits.

```cpp
for (char c : s) {
  if (isdigit(c)) {
    // sum += stoi(c);
    sum += c - '0';    
  }   
}

cout << sum;
```

Comment: Write it in the form of a pure, well-defined function and earn my upvote ;)

Comment: thanks, I din't know that you could convert str to int by -'0', this was really helpful, on internet it was always showing to use stoi() ,atoi() or stringstream().

Comment: You cannot convert a *string* to an int with that trick, only a character, see the loop. Because of ASCII you can get the value of the numerical representation by subtracting 48 off of it, since '0' has the value 48 this trick can be used. '0' through '9' are encoded with ASCII values 48 through 57, so you can see how subtracting 48 gives you the value you want. Using dedicated methods is more future proof in case we decide to ever move away from ASCII, however, that does not seem like something that would happen in the near future.